# How to create saturated color palette in Photoshop and Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color, palette

Assume that I have an A color with value 0xff0f0f and two basic black and white colors. How can I create quickly a swatch consists of all medium colors between white and A (lighter) and between A and black (darker)?

Edit: I'm practising some pixel-art shading, and I'd like to create a palette (or swatch) that consists of limited colors that differ from saturation = 0 to saturation = 1. For example:

[image: gradient]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In Photoshop:**

1. Draw a gradient with the end points you'd like.
2. Use Filter → Pixelate → Mosaic to step the gradient.

Once you've done that, you can use the eyedropper tool to add the colours to a swatch, or just leave the bitmap layer handy and use it to sample the colours as you need them (the layer itself can be your swatch).

You may also find Window → Extensions → Kuler or [kuler.adobe.com](http://kuler.adobe.com) handy.

Or... you could use a vector gradient (to keep it editable), then convert the layer to a Smart Object, then apply Mosaic as a Smart Filter. Very similar to the first solution, but you can edit the colours and number of steps at any point.

---

**In Illustrator:**

You could use the blend tool to create the colour variations.

1. Create two objects, one for each end of the gradient.
2. Use a stepped blend between the two.
3. Choose Object → Expand to turn the blend into editable objects.

[image: Blend Tool]

Or... you could use the [Color Guide panel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS8696149D-90D1-45e7-AA6A-967C95234F1Da.html), which can give you tints and shades of any colour.

Or... you could even create a gradient and then use Object → Rasterize to convert the gradient into a coarse bitmap (you may have to use a really low PPI when converting). You can then use the eyedropper tool to select the colours.

Or... create a bitmap colour swatch in Photoshop, then paste that into Illustrator and use the eyedropper tool to choose them.

Lots of options.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Creating a bitmap layer is a good choice for Photoshop. In Illustrator, it's a bit disturbing because I can't create Mosaic effect.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Illustrator can definitely do what you're after. The Color Guide panel could be *just* what you're after.